# how to Validate a Phone number so that it should not allow all same numerics like 99999999999 or 11111111111 in java

Tags: java, regex

how to Validate a Phone number so that it should not allow all same numerics like `99999999999` or `11111111111` in JAVA

thanks 
Sunny Mate

Comment: what are you gonna do when a user actually has the phone number 111 111 111 ?

Comment: There are many tools for phone number validation.  Try a google search of "phone number validation" for some options.

Comment: libphonenumber by google works well for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following regex:

```
^(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{10}$
```

matches 11 digit strings that do not have all the same digits.

A demo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] tests = {
                "11111111111",
                "99999999999",
                "99999999998",
                "12345678900"
        };
        for(String t : tests) {
            System.out.println(t+" :: "+t.matches("(\\d)(?!\\1+$)\\d{10}"));
        }
    }
}
```

which produces:

```
11111111111 :: false
99999999999 :: false
99999999998 :: true
12345678900 :: true
```

Comment: @Tony, thanks. It's a bit of fancy regex-trickery. I simply answered the question but I like the answers of @aioobe's (negating a less complicated pattern) and @TheBlastOne (addressing the probable issue behind the question) better.

Comment: @TheBlastOne has a good point.  Sometimes the programmer just has to do what they're told however.  @aioobe's solution would probably cause consternation.  Many companies seek out phone numbers with repeated digits and a less severe solution would reject them.  In fact, as I think about it, we likely do less harm with a hardcore solution like yours, or no validation at all.

Comment: >>Sometimes the programmer just has to do what they're told however.<<  I 100% agree, and understand that. But once you find out that the "feature" you just implemented feeds defects or data quality problems into your organization, and once you figure the same people who told you to protect against inplausible data will without hesitation command you to "repair the data!", "fix the phone input" NOW, the nonsense becomes clear. I, too, usually do what I am told. But if they tell me to fix a problem by hiding the symptoms, creating an even bigger problem, I deny.

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 1000 regex votes, they are well earned! This may be a good time to also say thanks for all the things I learned from you. Keep up the awesome work!

Comment: @Kobi, a-ha, I didn't know it went _that_ fast! I must say, tonight things were very easy: lots of regex question that were left alone for quite some time. I now see that you were just laying low to help me on some points towards 1K! :). Thanks for you kind words Kobi!

Comment: Not really, that wouldn't be good sport. it's a holiday `:)` Anyway, good night.

Answer (score 15):

If feasable, I'd try to discredit that requirement so it will be rejected.

No matter what you put into your plausibility checks, a user trying to avoid mandatory fields by entering junk into them will **always** succeed. You either end up having "smarter" harder-to-detect junk data items, or having a plausibility check which does not let all real-world data through into the system. Shit in, shit out. Build a shitshield, and your users will create fascies you never imagined.

There is no way to program around that (except for simple things that usually are unintended, erraneously entered typos and so on).

Comment: Exactly right. If users enter incorrect data, that should be a tell-tale sign that the field should not be mandatory. If the users see the field as important they would not input false data.

Comment: I'd second moving away from any over zealous validation on such fields. Another area where this seems to happen far too often is when people attempt email address validation, and and up disallowing perfectly valid characters like '+', '.', or '-' (arbitrary examples, and there are plenty more that occur in practice).

Comment: Doh! I was 99% sure you guys will yell at me for the vulgar language. Shows truth remains truth, no matter how clearly you articulate it. Great relief on my side, thanks.

Comment: we have a field for QA that is very mandatory, but users still put in fake numbers. Please don't assume because they put in fake info that it's not needed.

Answer (score 5):

This code matches numbers with at least 4 repeated numbers. (You could change the 3 in the regular expression to increase this threshold.)

```
Pattern sameDigits = Pattern.compile("(\\d)(\\1){3,}");

for (String num : new String[] {
        "11111",  // matches
        "1234",   // does not match
        "8584",   // does not match
        "999",    // does not match (too few repetitions)
        "9999"})  // matches

    if (sameDigits.matcher(num).matches())
        System.out.println("Same digits: " + num);
    else
        System.out.println("Not same digits: " + num);
```

Prints

```
Same digits: 11111
Not same digits: 1234
Not same digits: 8584
Not same digits: 999
Same digits: 9999
```