# Regex to match a phone number that is not composed of all the same number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that will match phone numbers that are not all composed of the same number.  I'm talking about a 10 digit phone number that looks like this (123)123-1234.  I've seen patterns that will match phones that *are* all the same, but I'm trying to match the opposite.

I've come up with this which is oh so close, but not quite there.

`^\((\d)(?!\1{2})\d{2}\)(?!\1{3})\d{3}-(?!\1{4})\d{4}$`

The only place this fails is when the area code is all the same number, everything else seems to work great.  So it will fail on something like this (888)123-1234, but will pass on (886)123-1234

How do I get it to accept that last hold out?

I've seen similar questions

[how to Validate a Phone number so that it should not allow all same numerics like 99999999999 or 11111111111 in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986651/how-to-validate-a-phone-number-so-that-it-should-not-allow-all-same-numerics-lik)

but this one doesn't account for the () and -, also it's matching the opposite of what I want.

and

[Regex to block a phone number that contains same digit more than 4 times successively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750585/regex-to-block-a-phone-number-that-contains-same-digit-more-than-4-times-success)

this kind of looks promising, but it doesn't account for the () and -.

Comment: Why not remove the `()` and `-` characters from the string before checking it?

Comment: Can you provide test cases of what is good and what is bad? I'm not seeing why `(888)123-1234` is good and `(886)123-1234` is bad. Or are you saying both should be good? If so, why?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I'm trying to add this as a pattern attribute on an html input

Comment: @KennethK., It's the other way around (888) is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
^\((\d)(?!\1{2}\)\1{3}-\1{4}$)\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ikZa5u/3)

Negative lookahead `(?!\1{2}\)\1{3}-\1{4}$)` will only fail the match if same digit is repeated all over from start to end.